# Reference for detailed exposition of Recursion/Computability Theory.

Tags: reference-request

I am looking for a reference that contains as much detail on recursion theory as possible. Many books that I am going through, such as *Computability Theory* by Barry Cooper and *Recursively Enumerable Sets and Degrees* by Robert Soare, avoid going into the rough details in proofs stating that they are often tedious. I am actually interested in finding the full proofs of things like the Kleene Normal Form Theorem, Enumeration Theorem, and S-M-N Theorems.